# Spring Singletons Passed into Other Objects

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting some odd behaviour from a program I'm writing and am curious about how beans are passed.

Here is the code (pseudocode... ish):

```
<bean id="Factory" class="com.xxx.xxx.Factory">
    <constructor-arg name="generator" ref="Generator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="Generator" class="com.xxx.xxx.Generator">
    <constructor-arg name="min" value="0"/>
    <constructor-arg name="max" value="5"/>
</bean>

class Generator {

    public Generator (min, max) {}

    public Integer getNextValue () {

        return nextValueInSequence; // min > max cyclically

    }

}


class Factory{

    public Factory (Generator generator) {

        ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        for (0 ... 4) {
            Object obj = new Object(generator);
            objects.add(obj);
        }

    }

}
```

My question is, should the list of `objects` contain the same `Generator` object?

For example:

Does `objects.get(0).getNextValue()` affect `objects.get(1).getNextValue()`?

i.e.

```
objects.get(0).getNextValue() > 2
objects.get(1).getNextValue() > 3
objects.get(0).getNextValue() > 4
```

I'm seeing different objects across the array.

Comment: does Object class has such kind of constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the generator in each object of the arraylist should be the same. Because spring beans are by default singleton.

have you done an `==` comparison on the generator objects in the arraylist? It should be true because all of them are the same object. And yes,

> objects.get(0).getNextValue() affects objects.get(1).getNextValue()

Is the `getNextValue()` implementation provided complete? Because logically calling `getNextValue()` sequentially on same object will always return different values.